# ExecuteNonQuery points to an older, non-existing database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, ssms

I'm getting a problem while testing/debugging a c# application with ssms database.
I'm testing commands on test databases, and I use different version numbers on them.
While debugging, I get an exception that one of the older versions does not exist (It really was deleted), but I am trying to query a different one.
During debugging, my command's "Connection" property shows the right database name.

I am assuming that something got stuck in the memory somewhere, but I have no idea where to look. Any ideas?

I am still a beginner with C# and MSSQL.

Thank you!

[Image of the Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48qBM.png)

Comment: your connection string is incorrect....

Comment: Don't post images - those are not useful for providing information and obviously cannot be searched nor can code be copied from it to examine it. Post the code that creates, populates, and executes your command so that others can examine it.

Comment: Do you mean Server (not database)?  A server can have more than one database.  Does the connection string use Attach File with an mdf file name?  If file is attached to the database you should not use the Attach File attribute.  Instead just use the server name.

Comment: @jdweng My Connection string looks like this: 
"Data Source=*my local pc name*\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=patika_probadb_v5;User ID=sa;Password=*****"
It just worked fine for some time, while I used v1, v2, v3...

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide us with detailed code.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I got it figured out! My problem was that I left a string in my stored procedure on the SQL server. There was nothing wrong with the VS code.
Mea Culpa

Comment: I suggest that you can give a reply and mark your reply as the answer. This will help many people which may face the similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it figured out! My problem was that I left a string in my stored procedure on the SQL server. There was nothing wrong with the VS code!
Mea Culpa

Thanks for commenting!

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer.